# Session with Database

Tags: php, database, session

I am a complete beginner who has been "experimenting" with PHP for quite some time.
Actually I'm very proud of my achievement so far, but slowly but surely I'm also doubting myself, I have the following code on page no. 1 place.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starte die Sitzung
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "vmaxdbweb");
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tblplatz");
// Tabellenbeginn
echo "<table class='tbl'>";
// Überschrift
echo "<th>ID</th> <th>Bezeichung</th> <th>Code</th>";
echo "<th>Notizen & Beurteilung</th> <th>Geodaten</th> <th>Details</th>";
$lf = 1;
while ($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
// Speichere die Daten in der Sitzung mit dem Schlüssel 'pla_id'
$_SESSION["detail"] = $dsatz["pla_id"];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $dsatz["pla_id"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $dsatz["pla_bezeichnung"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $dsatz["pla_code"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $dsatz["pla_notiz_beurteilung"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $dsatz["pla_geodaten"] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='content/placedetail.php'>Details</a></td>";
$lf = $lf + 1;
}
// Tabellenende
echo "</tabelle>";
mysqli_close($con);

?>
<table>
</table>
```

on page 2 placedetail.php I have this code

```
<?php
session_start();
// Hole den Wert der `pla_bezeichnung`-Spalte aus der Sitzung
$pla_bezeichnung = $_SESSION["detail"];
// Zeige die Details des jeweiligen Platzes an
echo "Der Platz heißt " . $pla_bezeichnung;
?>​
```

A value is also passed, but no matter which link I click in the table, it is always only a value from the last data record in the table. Go crazy slowly but surely.

I already found that the value is always overwritten because it's in a loop. How can I position the session better?

I've tried everything so far

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to obtain these values in a loop that grabs all the data from your db table?  Typically, a session is tied to an *individual* user.  Also, you *do not need* to run db queries in a loop (it's a common beginner's mistake because most db access tutorials feature grabbing multiple rows of data, but loops aren't always necessary)

Comment: Now they have me worried. I only knew the possibility of a loop to display the data of a database.

Comment: During the loop, `$_SESSION["detail"] = $dsatz["pla_id"];` overwrites the session value during each iteration of the loop

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Search for another possibility. Thanks.

Comment: If you only need 1 row of data from the db, remove the loop.

Comment: Put another way: your current db query says "get ALL rows from tblplatz."  Is that what you need?  If not, you'll need to refine your query (look into WHERE clauses) and adjust how you handle the results

Comment: I have several data that I want to read from the database

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that during the `while` loop, `$_SESSION["detail"] = $dsatz["pla_id"];` overwrites the session value at each iteration of the loop. So by the time you click to go to placedetail.php, the Session contains whatever was the last value which the loop processed.

But I don't see why you are using the Session here, it doesn't really make sense. If you want the placedetail.php to show a particular record, you should follow these steps:

1. Make the link in your table (in place.php) include the relevant record ID in the URL parameters
2. Write code in placedetail.php to receive that ID, and retrieve the rest of the details about it from the database.

place.php:

```
...
echo "<td><a href='content/placedetail.php?id=".$dsatz["pla_id"]."'>Details</a></td>";
...
```

placedetail.php

```
<?php
// Get the selected place using ID in the URL
$pla_id = $_GET["id"];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "vmaxdbweb");
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblplatz WHERE pla_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$rows = $result->fetch_all();

if (count($rows) > 0) {
  echo "Der Platz heißt " . $rows[0]["pla_bezeichnung"];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you!
I have read on many sites that using the URL is not a safe option

Comment: How would it not be safe? You can see a million sites on the internet that use parameters in the URL. It is essential to how the web works. Of course, if you send a password in the URL, or something like that, then it is not safe. But just sending the ID of the record you want to view is completely normal. Look at the structure of the URL of the page we are on right now: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76740612/session-with-database` ... here `76740612` is the ID of this specific question. (The structure of the URL is different in this case, but the basic idea is the same)

Comment: P.S. I would be interested to know what you have been reading, and where you read it. I wonder if you misunderstood something, or those sites were just talking nonsense.  I don't know what harm you think can come to your application if you use a URL parameter here?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly which side it was on, there were a lot. As a beginner you take everything. But I understand your code. Nothing is displayed on page 2, is this normal?

Comment: No, that should not be normal. Have you got PHP error reporting switched on? Have you done any debugging? Did you check that the ID is sent in your URL correctly when you go to to place.php? Did you check the contents of `$rows` to see what the query returns (if anything)?

Comment: I get the Problem, here is the code :)

<?php
// Get the selected place using ID in the URL
$pla_id = $_GET["id"];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "vmaxdbweb");
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblplatz WHERE pla_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $pla_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$rows = $result->fetch_all();

if (count($rows) > 0) {

echo "Der Platz heißt " . $rows[0][1]; // Verwende $rows[0][1] statt $rows[0]["pla_bezeichnung"]
echo "Messplatzcode " . $rows[0][2]; // Verwende $rows[0][1] statt $rows[0]["pla_bezeichnung"]
}
?>

Comment: What problem, exactly? Please be clear and specific, and reply to my enquiries directly. Otherwise it is very difficult to help you. Thankyou